Purpose of Microsoft L-80 Link Item - "External Offset"
Are there any old M80/L80 programmers out there that know what the Purpose of Microsoft L-80 Link Item - "External Offset" is?  [Link-80 Reference].
The special link item is defined in the Link-80 manual as:
8 External-offset. Used for JMP and CALL to externals
Now if may have something to do with this  [How to code a far absolute JMP/CALL instruction in MASM?] but given link-80 it was before segmented or paged memory; probably not.
Reading the manuals (links below) they make no explicit mention of this link item, except to say it is a valid Link item, so it must be an internally used link directive issued by the M80 assembler; if so what is its purpose?
The reasoning for the question is: when declaring a normal external, there is no need to declare any offset, just the symbol name and the linker/loader will resolve the reference and so the offset does not appear to have an obvious purpose even for JMPs or CALLs.
(https://altairclone.com/downloads/manuals/Microsoft%20L80%20Linker.pdf)
(https://altairclone.com/downloads/manuals/Microsoft%20M80%20Assembler.pdf)

Maybe it's used for ORG to change the linker's address counter, not for changing the address field of a JMP or CALL.

That would be a logical assumption is it were not for the fact that there is a link item "Set loading location counter to A" :-)   ( Probably used with the ORG Pseudo OP).  The more I think about it, it is probably a way of moving a module or procedure to a fixed address somewhere - but I am guessing.  But given there is no mention of it in the M80 manual it remains a mystery.
